# How could I pass my file name through this method?

Tags: python

I am taking a screenshot, and then I need to reference the shot I just took so I can translate what's inside it.

When I directly pass a file location, e.g "filex.png", to `readtext`, it works, but I just need it to pass the written file into it.

```py
import easyocr
import pyautogui
import time
import cv2 
import numpy as np

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
tag = 1

for i in range(2):
    time.sleep(4)
    image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(630,400,650,130))
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image),
                     cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    tag+=1

    img = cv2.imwrite(f"image{tag}.png", image)


    results = reader.readtext(img)
    text=""
    for result in results:
        text += result[1] + " "

        print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your specific question, I think you're looking for something like:

```py
import easyocr
import pyautogui
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
tag = 1

for i in range(2):
    time.sleep(4)
    image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(630, 400, 650, 130))
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    tag += 1

    f_name = f"image{tag}.png"
    cv2.imwrite(f_name, image)
    results = reader.readtext(f_name)
    
    text = ""
    for result in results:
        text += result[1] + " "

        print(text)
```

You can just store your file name in a variable in pass it to both `imwrite` and `readtext`

---

There are other options as well, depending on what information you need access to within the program, and how quickly you need to process your data.

Option: Pass the `np.array` directly to `readtext`

```py
image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(630, 400, 650, 130))
image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
results = reader.readtext(image)
```

Option: Pass the data from the written file to the `readtext` function.

```py
f_name = f"image{tag}.png"
cv2.imwrite(f_name, image)

with open(f_name, 'rb') as f:
    results = reader.readtext(f.read())
```

Comment: The documentation for EasyOCR's reader also says that you can create it by giving a numpy array as a first argument, which should mean that reader.readext(image) will work as well - it would save you time to do this if you are processing many images in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
import easyocr
import numpy as np

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'],gpu=False)
im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(630,400,650,130)
result = reader.readtext(np.array(im),detail = 0)
```

just pass the pyautogui image as **np.array**